# Autoupdate shows current when I'm on 3.1

Tags: updates, automatic-updates

My host has Fantastico set to install version 3.1. 
But when I go to Dashboard/Updates, it says "You have the latest version of WordPress."

I clicked "Check again" and it says: Last checked on August 5, 2013 at 5:07 am.

Why won't it detect 3.5 or 3.6? Is this related to my hosting company?  Or is it checking directly to WordPress site?

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably just installing it from a package, it would be quite unwise from a security standpoint to let fantastico load directly from a remote server. Meaning I don´t think they are allowed to do it. Simply install wordpress from ftp should do it.

Comment: My question is more this: AFTER installing with Fantastico, why doesn't the auto-detect "Check Update" detect it needs a new release?

Comment: Because your provider have not updated their version probably, where they have rerouted the server to check internally instead at wordpress.org.